# zsh: command not found: go | installed go but not showing in terminal

Tags: macos, go, installation, apple-m1

When you will try to install the go and you check it in your terminal

This error will show up

```
zsh: command not found: go
```

You installed go but not showing in terminal

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Add this to it

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin 
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Exit with Cntrl + X then click Yes

Open new terminal and check with

```
go version
```